# how to conditionally concatenate fields in mongodb aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to build a string from concatenating some fields, but I want to check the value of each field before I decide to concatenate it.

```
//syntax:
{$projection:{fieldName:{$concat:["$field1","-","$field2","$field3"]}}}
```

what I want?

```
fieldName=($field1!=null?"$field1-":"")+"$field2"+($field3=="ok"?"approved":"pending")
```

Answer (score 8):

For the first case (null), you would use the `$ifNull` operator.  This will return a default value if the field is null or missing.

For the second case, use the `$cond` operator.

```js
fieldName:{
 $concat:
 [
  {$ifNull:["$field1", ""]},
  "-",
  "$field2", 
  {$cond:[{$eq:['$field3', 'ok']}, "approved", "pending"] }
 ]
}
```